# Searching for method definitions with cscope and ctags (or anything else)

Tags: ctags, cscope

Is there a way to search for method definition with some Vim plugin? Suppose there's a method with rather generic name, something like

```
User user;
cout << user.get_name() << endl;
```

Is there a way to jump immediately to `User` class without browsing through multiple files that define `get_name` method for other classes?

Comment: Also see `:help g]` (which searches the ctags database) to get a list of files where this function is defined/declared.

Comment: The function `get_name` could be defined in tens of files, is there a way to pinpoint specific one?